# ( PMBOK 5th Edition ) What is difference between Quality Audit and Process Analysis?

Tags: pmp, quality, quality-management, pmbok, process-improvement

For the PMBOK 5th Edition.

2 of the Perform Quality Assurance Tools & Techniques are

-Quality Audit

-Process Analysis

(  Pgs 438-439,  Head First PMP 3rd Edition, Jennifer Greene, PMP & Andrew Stellman, PMP )

"Quality Audits are reviews of your project by your company.  They figure out whether or not you are following the company's process."

"Process Analysis is when you look at your process to find out how to make it better.  You use your Process Improvement plan to do this one."

(  Pgs 438-439,  Head First PMP 3rd Edition, Jennifer Greene, PMP & Andrew Stellman, PMP )

(   Pgs 408-409  , PMP Project Management Professional Exam Study Guide, Kim Heldman, PMP )

"The purpose of a quality audit.....to identify ineffective and inefficient activities or processes used on the project."

"Process Analysis looks at process improvement from an organizational and technical perspective......

.....process analysis follows the steps in the process improvement plan and examines the following:

-Problems experienced while conducting the project

-Constraints experienced while conducting the work of the project

-Inefficient and Ineffective activities identified during process operation"

(   Pgs 408-409  , PMP Project Management Professional Exam Study Guide, Kim Heldman, PMP )

It seems to me that both PMP study guides don't say the same thing.

Could someone please provide definitions for Quality Audit and Process Analysis, and explain the difference between the said two terms?

Comment: Laconic: You should put answers down in the answers section, not in the comments so that people can vote on and accept them.

Comment: @Daniel - I didn't really have time to formulate a full answer, so thought it better left as a comment. If you think it contains sufficient detail, I'll be happy to promote it.

Comment: @LaconicDroid Just put it as an answer :)

Comment: Comment moved to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quality Audit is basically seeing if you are following the defined process. A Process Analysis is examining what you do and identifying aspects that could be improved.

As an extreme example, in a Quality Audit you might have a process that says "Every employee should sleep for 10 minutes per hour" and the Audit would have to confirm it was being followed.

A Process Analysis may find that sleeping for 10 minutes every hour was not an efficient way to work.